# How to manage `maxLength` of `textfield` with two dependent fileds in `extjs`

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to set `maxLength` of two dependent fields in one `textfield`?

```
get_input_field: function (target_field, name) {
    return ({
        xtype: "textfield",
        name: name,
        width: 100,
        autoCreate: {
            tag: "input",
            maxLength: 10,
            type: "text",
            size: "20",
            autoComplete: "off"
        },
        value: this[name],
        listeners: this.get_listeners(target_field)

    })
}
```

the dependent fields are:

```
 this.get_input_field("dependentField1", "upperValue")
 this.get_input_field("dependentField2", "lowerValue")
```

Please help me how to fix `maxLength` based on these two fields.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u explain it more